# connecting to local apache2 server from within local network

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, localhost

On machine X I can connect to 127.0.1.1 (I have a php script running on machine X that calls phpinfo() and it runs fine). X machines IP on the network is 192.168.1.101. I go over to machine Y and type in 192.168.1.101 in the browser address bar expecting to see the phpinput() output. Instead, I get a 'server timed out' error.

Somehow, there must be a way to 'connect' 192.168.1.101 to the apache2 server. What is this? Assume no firewall issues.

```
iptables -L : (per request)

Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:netbios-ns 
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:netbios-dgm 
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:netbios-ssn 
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:microsoft-ds 
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootps 
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:bootpc 
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST 

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix `[UFW BLOCK] ' 

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix `[UFW BLOCK] ' 

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp destination-unreachable 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp source-quench 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp time-exceeded 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp parameter-problem 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc 
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  base-address.mcast.net/4  anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             base-address.mcast.net/4 
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix `[UFW ALLOW] ' 

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10 
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix `[UFW BLOCK] ' 

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL 
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST 
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST 
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW 

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:smtp 
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:smtp 
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:www 

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix `[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] ' 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: `iptables -L` or it didn't happen.

Comment: Is apache on machine X configured to listen on port 80 at IP 192.168.1.101? You only tested that it successfully accepts connections on a local IP (127.0.1.1).

Comment: > Is apache on machine X configured to listen on port 80 at IP 192.168.1.101?  Apparently not. Googling how to do this now.

Comment: Since we get to assume no firewall issues, can we assume you stopped the firewall and tried to connect?

Comment: @aseq What IP address does machine Y have - and does it have a firewall?  Can machine Y ping machine X?

Comment: Y = 192.168.1.102 and is a windows machine with the firewall turned off. X = 192.168.1.101 and is an ubuntu machine with the firewall turned off. I can ping either from either.

Answer (score 1):

List out your httpd.conf file and see what Apache is listening on. Odds are that its only listening to localhost.

`cat /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf | grep -i listen`

If that's the case, add a line to allow it to listen on its IP address or a port.

Another possibility is that your firewall is blocking communication with your web server. `iptables -L` would dispel (or confirm) that notion.

Comment: Im on Ubuntu, and from my research, it seems that apache2.conf takes the place of httpd.conf (please confirm?). In there, there is a line referencing ports : Include /etc/apache2/ports.conf. In ports.conf there is a line with listen : Listen 80. So, it seems apache IS set up to listen on port 80, right?

Comment: @jason My understanding of Debian based distributions is that apache2.conf is standardized, however the normal Apache hierarchy of Apache.conf -> httpd.conf -> vhosts still exists. Yes, that means that Apache is listening on port 80.

Comment: Still cant access it from machine Y.